# How do I download other players' replays?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

It says that you can view replays that you've downloaded from other players, but so far, I can't find out where to go to download them. Is there a specific menu in which you can download replays from other players?

Any answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can download replays only from viewing the "Player License" of another player. You can get to that from various places, such as the "Soul Link" if they're marked as your rival, a multiplayer match while you're still connected and in the lobby with them, or your Battle Log in the Replay section of online multiplayer.

If you want to find the Player License of a friend that you haven't played against recently or registered as a rival, you can do that from the Leaderboards. Just switch the Filter a couple of times until it's only showing you and your friends list.

Once you're in the Player License, there should be an indicator telling you which button to press to download their replays. On Xbox 360 it's X, so I'm guessing it would be Square on PS3.